# how to make editable choice's answer in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

is it possible in a batch file to make editable choice ? like-

Enter server name :localhost

this localhost will appears by default, and now user can edit it and can write new server name, by deleting localhost.

can anybody suggest me the right way for doing so...

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

SET /P does not change the value of the target variable if the user presses `<Enter>` without entering any data. So you can set the default value before executing SET /P, and then the user can override by entering a new value or accept the default by pressing `<Enter>`.

```
@echo off
set "server=:localhost"
set /p "server=Enter server (default=%server%): "
echo the user chose server=%server%
```